# Sorting words (not lines) in VIM

Tags: bash, vim

The built-in VIM `:sort` command sorts lines of text. I want to sort words in a single line, e.g. transform the line

```
b a d c e f
```

to

```
a b c d e f
```

Currently I accomplish this by selecting the line and then using `:!tr ' ' '\n' | sort | tr '\n' ' '`, but I'm sure there's a better, simpler, quicker way. Is there?

Note that I use bash so if there's a shorter and more elegant bash command for doing this it's also fine.

**EDIT:** My use-case is that I have a line that says `SOME_VARIABLE="one two three four etc"` and I want the words in that variable to be sorted, i.e. I want to have `SOME_VARIABLE="etc four one three two"`.

The end result should preferably be mappable to a shortcut key as this is something I find myself needing quite often.

Comment: This is one of those occasions where I think the disease is better than the cure.  In particular, I think your `tr` recipe is much better than those proposed here as answers.

Comment: An alternative is `!tr ' ' \\n | sort | xargs`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using great ideas from your answers, especially Al's answer, I eventually came up with the following:

```
:vnoremap <F2> d:execute 'normal i' . join(sort(split(getreg('"'))), ' ')<CR>
```

This maps the <kbd>F2</kbd> button in `visual` mode to delete the selected text, split, sort and join it and then re-insert it. When the selection spans multiple lines this will sort the words in all of them and output one sorted line, which I can quickly fix using `gqq`.

I'll be glad to hear suggestions on how this can be further improved.

Many thanks, I've learned a lot :)

**EDIT**: Changed `'<C-R>"'` to `getreg('"')` to handle text with the char `'` in it.

Comment: +1 Nice! One comment is that if I have a line "abc def ghi", and select + sort "def ghi", it seems to remove the space before the first word and append it after the last one, instead of preserving it.

Comment: I had the same problem. Change `'normal i'` to `'normal a'` to solve it.

Comment: If you use this to sort a list of comma-delimited words it won't handle redistributing the commas.

Answer (score 28):

In pure vim, you could do this:

```
call setline('.', join(sort(split(getline('.'), ' ')), " "))
```

**Edit**

To do this so that it works over a range that is less than one line is a little more complicated (this allows either sorting multiple lines individually or sorting part of one line, depending on the visual selection):

```
command! -nargs=0 -range SortWords call SortWords()
" Add a mapping, go to your string, then press vi",s
" vi" selects everything inside the quotation
" ,s calls the sorting algorithm
vmap ,s :SortWords<CR>
" Normal mode one: ,s to select the string and sort it
nmap ,s vi",s
function! SortWords()
    " Get the visual mark points
    let StartPosition = getpos("'<")
    let EndPosition = getpos("'>")

    if StartPosition[0] != EndPosition[0]
        echoerr "Range spans multiple buffers"
    elseif StartPosition[1] != EndPosition[1]
        " This is a multiple line range, probably easiest to work line wise

        " This could be made a lot more complicated and sort the whole
        " lot, but that would require thoughts on how many
        " words/characters on each line, so that can be an exercise for
        " the reader!
        for LineNum in range(StartPosition[1], EndPosition[1])
            call setline(LineNum, join(sort(split(getline('.'), ' ')), " "))
        endfor
    else
        " Single line range, sort words
        let CurrentLine = getline(StartPosition[1])

        " Split the line into the prefix, the selected bit and the suffix

        " The start bit
        if StartPosition[2] > 1
            let StartOfLine = CurrentLine[:StartPosition[2]-2]
        else
            let StartOfLine = ""
        endif
        " The end bit
        if EndPosition[2] < len(CurrentLine)
            let EndOfLine = CurrentLine[EndPosition[2]:]
        else
            let EndOfLine = ""
        endif
        " The middle bit
        let BitToSort = CurrentLine[StartPosition[2]-1:EndPosition[2]-1]

        " Move spaces at the start of the section to variable StartOfLine
        while BitToSort[0] == ' '
            let BitToSort = BitToSort[1:]
            let StartOfLine .= ' '
        endwhile
        " Move spaces at the end of the section to variable EndOfLine
        while BitToSort[len(BitToSort)-1] == ' '
            let BitToSort = BitToSort[:len(BitToSort)-2]
            let EndOfLine = ' ' . EndOfLine
        endwhile

        " Sort the middle bit
        let Sorted = join(sort(split(BitToSort, ' ')), ' ')
        " Reform the line
        let NewLine = StartOfLine . Sorted . EndOfLine
        " Write it out
        call setline(StartPosition[1], NewLine)
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: How would I modify this to sort the words of the selected text instead of the whole line?

Comment: @depesz - Sure, but it sorts the entire line, I asked how to sort the selected text.

Comment: @spatz: Sorting part of a line is rather complicated as commands can't take sub-line ranges, but I've added an example of how to do this.

Answer (score 14):

Here's the equivalent in pure vimscript:

```
 :call setline('.',join(sort(split(getline('.'),' ')),' '))
```

It's no shorter or simpler, but if this is something you do often, you can run it across a range of lines:

```
 :%call setline('.',join(sort(split(getline('.'),' ')),' '))
```

Or make a command

```
 :command -nargs=0 -range SortLine <line1>,<line2>call setline('.',join(sort(split(getline('.'),' ')),' '))
```

Which you can use with

```
:SortLine
:'<,'>SortLine
:%SortLine
```

etc etc

Comment: As @spatz mentioned in the comment for answer from @Al, this sorts the whole line, not a selection on the line.

Comment: @rampion Nice solution. Can you explain your 2 use case `:'<,'>SortLine` ?

Comment: @SebMa - sure; when switching from visual mode to command mode with `:`, vim autopopulates the command line with `'<,'>`. This is an example of a command line range, often used to indicate a set of lines. In this case `'<` means the first line in the visual selection and `'>` means the last line in the visual selection. Ranges can also be specified using actual line numbers (e.g. `112,499`) or use some other special characters, like `^` for the first line of the file and `$` for the last.  When given a range, `call` runs the given expression on each line in the range.  SortLine does the same.

Answer (score 7):

```
:!perl -ne '$,=" ";print sort split /\s+/'
```

Not sure if it requires explanation, but if yes:

```
perl -ne ''
```

runs whatever is within '' for every line in input - putting the line in default variable $_.

```
$,=" ";
```

Sets list output separator to space. For example:

```
=> perl -e 'print 1,2,3'
123

=> perl -e '$,=" ";print 1,2,3'
1 2 3

=> perl -e '$,=", ";print 1,2,3'
1, 2, 3
```

Pretty simple.

```
print sort split /\s+/
```

Is shortened version of:

```
print( sort( split( /\s+/, $_ ) ) )
```

($_ at the end is default variable).

split - splits $_ to array using given regexp, sort sorts given list, print - prints it.

Comment: I'd hardly say a convoluted Perl script is an improvement…

Comment: I loved it. Simple and elegant.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you prefer Python:

```
!python -c "import sys; print(' '.join(sorted(sys.stdin.read().split())))"
```

Visual select text, and execute this line.

Comment: Still new to some of the language integration into Vim, but does this use compiled-in Python support or use an external executable?

Comment: To clarify, it does not use compiled-in python support in vim. It uses the external python binary as a shell command.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I wasn't aware we are talking about this one-liner. I thought we are talking about Vim at general.

Answer (score 3):

My [AdvancedSorters plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4958) now has a `:SortWORDs` command that does this (among other sorting-related commands).

Comment: Works really fine! Thanks for the plugin!