# Vim: Convert map to command

Tags: vim

I'd like to convert [this `map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327978/sorting-words-not-lines-in-vim/1329899#1329899) to a `command`. I've tried the "obvious," copying the command part of the `map` line to a `command` line:

```
command SortWords d:execute 'normal i' . join(sort(split(getreg('"'))), ' ')<CR>
```

However, when using this with selected text it just fails with "`E481: No range allowed`". My Google-fu is not strong enough, and the manual is ... computer parseable, let's say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
command! -nargs=0 -range SortWords exe 'norm! gvd'|call setreg('"', join(sort(split(@")), ' '), visualmode()[0])|norm! P
```

This command is dirty as it clobbers the unnamed register.

To avoid this you must save the register and restore it when you are done. The best way to do this is by using a function.

```
command! -nargs=0 -range SortWords call VisualSortWords()

function! VisualSortWords()
  let rv = @"
  let rt = getregtype('"')
  try
    norm! gvy
    call setreg('"', join(sort(split(@")), ' '), visualmode()[0])
    norm! `>pgvd
  finally
    call setreg('"', rv, rt)
  endtry
endfunction
```

Comment: If you could change this to avoid changing the character *before* the selection (when selecting a subset of the words), I'd mark it as accepted.

Comment: @l0b0: I do not see this behavior. Could you please give me some before and after text?

Comment: Create a file containing `abc ghi def`, mark "`ghi def`" (and *not* the preceding space), `:'<,'>SortWords`. The result: `abcdef ghi ` (with a space at the end).

Comment: @l0b0: I have fixed the edge case if the selection is at the end of the line.

Comment: Using the multi-line command (the single line command still changes the character before the selection), if I select to the end of the line, it removes the first character of the result. That is, with a line `f e d`, if I select from `e` to EOL and sort it I end up with `<space>e` rather than the expected `d e`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a different approach that makes use of only 2 commands ([:call](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#%3acall) and
[:delete](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#%3adelete)). The process is explained below.

```
command! -range -nargs=0 Sort
  \ call append(<line2>,join(sort(split(join(getline(<line1>,<line2>)))), ' ')) |
  \ <line1>,<line2>d _
```

Notice that I used 3 lines with the correspondent continuation characters for
the sake of readability, but you could have used only one.

#### The command itself

The command is defined as "Sort" and has two special characteristics:

- `-range` makes it able to receive a range, obviously. Also, it sets the
  default range to the current line (see help for [:command-range](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#%3acommand-range)).
- `-nargs=0` could be omitted, as it will only guarantee that you or future
  users of your command won't pass any arguments to it.

Before the command is processed, the text marked as `<line1>` will be replaced
by the line number of the range start. Similarly, `<line2>` will be replaced by
the line number of the range end. Check help on [<line1>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#%3Cline1%3E) and subsequent
lines to know more about replacement text in commands.

#### What it does

The command will execute its task in two takes. The first is a chain of
functions that can be read from inside out. Let's consider the command was
called with a visual selection range (`'<`, `'>`) that translates as (1,3). The
functions will be executed as:

```
append(3, join(sort(split(join(getline(1,3)))), ' '))
```

From a different point of view:

```
#1 getline(1,3)  " the result is a list with text from lines 1 to 3
#2 join(#1)      " joins that list into a string
#3 split(#2)     " splits the string on whitespace, resulting in a list
#4 sort(#3)      " sorts that list
#5 join(#4, ' ') " joins the elements into a string separated by single space
#6 append(3, #5) " insert that string after line 3
```

If you started with this text:

```
f e
d c
b a
```

Now you should have this:

```
f e
d c
b a
a b c d e f
```

It's just a matter of deleting those lines. This is exactly that the next part
of the command does:

```
1,3d _
```

`d` is a short for the ex command [:delete](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#%3adelete), and `_` is the register to put
the deleted text in. In this case, it's the [black hole](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#quote_) register.

Comment: Nice explanation! Sadly this only works linewise, and the previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327978/sorting-words-not-lines-in-vim/1329899 mentions doing this characterwise.

Comment: Thanks @Peter! Yeah, although it mentions character-wise selections, generally ex commands are line-wise. By the way, ex is the line editor :-) So I believe that OP had this in mind when opting for a command instead of the traditional map. I can't remember a command not line-wise in Vim (if you know, please tell me). But your solution is really great (that's why I upvoted it :-P ) , here I just tried to avoid external functions to do the work.

Comment: I find your solution to be very nice. Commands w/o functions are the best! I would probably have used `<line2>pu=join(...`, as I forgot about append. As for characterwise range ex commands I doubt there are any.

Comment: Nice, but I *did* want to work on character-wise ranges (For example, to sort an `enum` range). If that's not feasible with a command I'd rather go with a function.