# Sort line (horizontally) in VIM

Tags: vim

I know that it's very easy to do sort operations in vim through build in command `sort`.
But how to sort just one line and text within that line horizontally?

e.g. from this point `(aaa ccc bbb)`
to this `(aaa bbb ccc)`

I tried `vi(:sort` but it doesn't helped me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327978/sorting-words-not-lines-in-vim

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
:s/\s\+/\r/g    " break the line into multiple ones
:'[,sort       " sort them
:,']j          " join them
```

Comment: +1 but I had to remove the `*` to make it work. The `*` matches all characters, not just repeating the `\s`. I thought it might be a setting but starting vim with `-u NONE` didn't help either. Using `\v\s+`worked for me. The command I finally used was `s/\v\s+/\r/g|'[,sort|,']j`

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers, you are right about `*`, thanks for spotting my error. Actually, `\s*` doesn't match all characters: it matches *zero or more* whitespace characters, that's a zero-width match which corresponds to every "space" between characters. I was clearly thinking about something else while posting that answer.

Comment: lol, thank you but I didn't spot anything. I actually assumed it was a bug with my *(recently altered)* vim installation.